# Twitch API LOGIN. Safari redirects me

Tags: swift, oauth, twitch

Building an app with swift, in witch I have login trough twitch.

```
https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=////&redirect_uri=////&response_type=code&scope=viewing_activity_read&force_verify=true
```

If I run this code trough safari on desktop, it shows me the app authentication screen.

If I do this on mobile, it redirects me to `twitch.tv/login?no-mobile-redirect=true`

WTF should I do?

Comment: Did you resolve it?